# wordpress latest posts to be included on a smarty template site (wordpress is on a subdomain)

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a main site (which uses this software http://geodesicsolutions.com and smarty templates) with a wordpress blog on a subdomain.

I want to include my latest blog posts on the main site which would ideally mean placing the code below on a smart template file on my main site, but this isn't working.

```
<?php require('YourSubDirectory/wp-blog-header.php');?>
<?php   
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
echo '<ul id="latest_posts">';
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
<li><strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong><br />
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This is the feedback from geodesic solutions, if anyone can help further/knows a way to achieve what I need, it would be very much appreciated!

> 3) You cannot place php directly into Smarty templates anymore....at
>   least by default.  You can dip into the hardcoded configurations for
>   smarty within the base code set but would suggest pulling something in
>   using js at the browser level instead.  Is there an rss feed from your
>   blog that can be included at the browser level using js?  The choice
>   is your how you pull them in.